# Change the default configuration or add more settings to user create with rbash

Tags: linux, bash

How can I change or add more settings when I create a user with rbash

`useradd peter2 -s /bin/rbash`

I found this article to create a limited user but want to change the default configuration
[How to Use Restricted Shell to Limit What a Linux User Can Do](https://www.howtogeek.com/718074/how-to-use-restricted-shell-to-limit-what-a-linux-user-can-do/)

[6.10 The Restricted Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html)

When i want to make more changes like them:

> When you run Bash as a restricted shell, the user has some capabilities removed from them. Specifically, the user cannot:

```
Use cd to change the working directory.
Change the values of the $PATH , $SHELL , $BASH_ENV , or $ENV environmental variables (but they can read the current values).
Read or change $SHELLOPTS shell environmental options.
Redirect the output of a command.
Invoke commands that require a path to locate them. That is, you can’t issue a command that has one or more forward slashes “/” in it.
Invoke exec to substitute a different process for the shell.
Use any of the restricted features in a script.
```

- Where are these restrictions stored
- Add or delete more commands

Comment: The question is not clear. What kind of settings would you like to change/add?